# Android : Realm Migration Issue

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I am new to android and I used realm in my APP but I didn't specified the schemaversion then, now when I want to upgrade the app and implement migration.

Previously, I was doing this,

```
Realm.init(getApplicationContext());

RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration =
                        new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();

realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```

And now,

```
Realm.init(getApplicationContext());

RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration =
                            new RealmConfiguration.Builder().schemaVersion(1).migration(new Migration()).build();

realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```

And, I am getting this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file. 
Cached configuration: 
realmDirectory: /data/user/0/in.avanti_app.student_companion.debug/files
realmFileName : default.realm
canonicalPath: /data/data/in.avanti_app.student_companion.debug/files/default.realm
key: [length: 0]
schemaVersion: 1
migration: in.avanti_app.student_companion.realmClasses.Migration@25
deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false
durability: FULL
schemaMediator: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator@793ec9a4

New configuration: 
realmDirectory: /data/user/0/in.avanti_app.student_companion.debug/files
realmFileName : default.realm
canonicalPath: /data/data/in.avanti_app.student_companion.debug/files/default.realm
key: [length: 0]
schemaVersion: 0
migration: null
deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false
durability: FULL
schemaMediator: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator@793ec9a4
```

I also override the hasCode and equals in Migration class.

Comment: `I also override the hasCode and equals in Migration class.` please show relevant code

Comment: Although it seems to claim that you have a configuration with `schemaVersion1` and `schemaVersion0`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
   Overirde
    public int hashCode() {
        return Migration.class.hashCode();
    }

   Overirde
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof Migration);
    }
 
    Overirde
    public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    //migration logic
   }
}

Comment: You are creating a new RealmConfiguration somewhere in your code that does not have the new schema version and migration specified.

Comment: No, I have checked that part.

Comment: You might be calling `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` somewhere without having specified the `Realm.setDefaultInstance()`

Comment: Yeah @EpicPandaForce, that solved the issue but I had only 1 instance, shouldn't it be the default?

Comment: No, it's not the default unless you set the configuration as default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Realm.init(Context)` initializes a "default configuration" in the following code

```
public static synchronized void init(Context context) {
    if (BaseRealm.applicationContext == null) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-null context required.");
        }
        RealmCore.loadLibrary(context);
        defaultConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
        ObjectServerFacade.getSyncFacadeIfPossible().init(context);
        BaseRealm.applicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        SharedRealm.initialize(new File(context.getFilesDir(), ".realm.temp"));
    }
}
```

But `new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build();` sets a configuration without schema version, migration, `deleteIfMigrationNeeded()`, etc

In order to set a new default configuration, you need to create your config and then call `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);`

---

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration =
         new RealmConfiguration.Builder().schemaVersion(1).migration(new Migration()).build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```